# Why does gunicorn need to restart so often in my gcloud appengine app?

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, gunicorn, gcloud

I am using Flask to run an application.  The application will be deployed on gcloud appengine.  Currently, when I run it on my local dev machine, there is no issue.  But when I run it on gcloud appengine, it appears that the gunicorn thread is being restarted quite often.

```
2022-11-13 08:54:13 default[20221113t165059]  Other load
2022-11-13 08:54:13 default[20221113t165059]  post.get_by_pageid
2022-11-13 08:54:13 default[20221113t165059]  Returning posts 0 to  4
2022-11-13 08:54:15 default[20221113t165059]  "GET /view/tree/61e2b6585fc8f37d73f59218? HTTP/1.1" 201
2022-11-13 08:54:15 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:15 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-11-13 08:54:15 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:15 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (9)
2022-11-13 08:54:15 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:15 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2022-11-13 08:54:15 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:15 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2022-11-13 08:54:16 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:16 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2022-11-13 08:54:16 default[20221113t165059]  I1113 08:54:16.841506    22 __init__.py:52] Initializing Cloud Debugger Python agent version: 3.1
2022-11-13 08:54:16 default[20221113t165059]  I1113 08:54:16.841692    19 __init__.py:52] Initializing Cloud Debugger Python agent version: 3.1
2022-11-13 08:54:17 default[20221113t165059]  I1113 08:54:17.034071    24 gcp_hub_client.py:377] Debuggee registered successfully, ID: gcp:431135224927:32ede2785bfa47c7, 
agent ID: 636e418c-0000-2d3e-8038-089e08203644, canary mode: CANARY_MODE_ALWAYS_ENABLED
2022-11-13 08:54:17 default[20221113t165059]  I1113 08:54:17.034071    23 gcp_hub_client.py:377] Debuggee registered successfully, ID: gcp:431135224927:32ede2785bfa47c7, agent ID: 636d1d19-0000-23d2-bc11-089e082c7780, canary mode: CANARY_MODE_ALWAYS_ENABLED
2022-11-13 08:54:17 default[20221113t165059]  secureCheckLoggedIn
2022-11-13 08:54:17 default[20221113t165059]  SCLI Not Logged In
2022-11-13 08:54:17 default[20221113t165059]  view tree
2022-11-13 08:54:17 default[20221113t165059]  page.get
2022-11-13 08:54:19 default[20221113t165059]  "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404
2022-11-13 08:54:19 default[20221113t165059]  page.get_user_pages
2022-11-13 08:54:19 default[20221113t165059]  page.get_latest
2022-11-13 08:54:20 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:20 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-11-13 08:54:20 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:20 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11)
2022-11-13 08:54:20 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:20 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2022-11-13 08:54:20 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:20 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2022-11-13 08:54:20 default[20221113t165059]  [2022-11-13 08:54:20 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2022-11-13 08:54:21 default[20221113t165059]  I1113 08:54:21.078205    22 __init__.py:52] Initializing Cloud Debugger Python agent version: 3.1
2022-11-13 08:54:21 default[20221113t165059]  I1113 08:54:21.078326    19 __init__.py:52] Initializing Cloud Debugger Python agent version: 3.1
2022-11-13 08:54:21 default[20221113t165059]  "GET /load?c=0 HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-13 08:54:21 default[20221113t165059]  secureCheckLoggedIn
2022-11-13 08:54:21 default[20221113t165059]  SCLI Not Logged In
```

Gunicorn is restarted twice in the space of 2 seconds.  Every time the thread restarts, it invalidates the previous stored session variables.

How do I fix this please?  Just in case, here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python38

env_variables:
    PASSWORD: "XXXXXXXXX"
    SENDGRID_API_KEY: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

app_engine_apis: true

handlers:
    - url: /static
      static_dir: static

    - url: /.*
      script: auto
```

P.S. secureCheckLoggedIn, Page.... are all my debug printing.

Comment: Does your app consume a lot of memory?  You might be exceeding memory but you should see log messages about that.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think so.  My app uses MongoDB and most of the operations are the results of filtering the DB.  Also the DB is small at this point in time.  App also does not use memory hungry libraries like TF etc..  The front end runs D3 but the problem I see is on the back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many apologies.  I found that the reason why my session (run off MongoDB) was so unstable.  The reason is because for the

```
secretKey = os.urandom(21)  # your own secret key
```

So every time gunicorn reinitialized itself (I don't know the reason why though), all the code infront of that which required to have the same secret_key was thrashed on gcloud.  No such problems for my local dev machine though.  I changed secretKey to a fixed string and that solved it on gcloud.